# Creating an instance and calling a method from an enum, JAVA

Tags: java, enums

I Have an enum class Direction with one method which is suppoused to return a random direction (North, East, South or West) and I want to call it from the main method of another class which is in the same package. However I can't do that since I can't call a non static from a static method. So I tried creating an instance of the enum class Direction, but so far I can remember the constructor of all enum types is private and they can't be instanced. So how am I suppouse to call a method from an enum class.

```
package battleship;

public enum Direction {
/**
 * The North Direction (where y decreases)
 */
NORTH,

/**
 * The East Direction (where x increases)
 */
EAST,

/**
 * The South Direction (where y increases)
 */
SOUTH,

/**
 * The West Direction (where x decreases)
 */
WEST;

Direction getDirection() {
    Direction direction = null;
    int dir = (int) (Math.random() * 4);
    switch (dir) {
    case 0: direction = Direction.NORTH;  break;
    case 1: direction = Direction.EAST;  break;
    case 2: direction = Direction.WEST;  break;
    case 3: direction = Direction.SOUTH;  break;
    }
    return direction;
}
}

package battleship;

public class SeaTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Sea sea = new Sea(10, 10);
    Direction dir = new Direction();

    sea.addShip(ShipType.MINESWEEPER, dir.getDirection(), (int)(Math.random() * 11), (int)(Math.random() * 11));
    sea.addShip(ShipType.MINESWEEPER, dir.getDirection(), (int)(Math.random() * 11), (int)(Math.random() * 11));
    sea.addShip(ShipType.MINESWEEPER, dir.getDirection(), (int)(Math.random() * 11), (int)(Math.random() * 11));
    sea.addShip(ShipType.MINESWEEPER, dir.getDirection(), (int)(Math.random() * 11), (int)(Math.random() * 11));
    sea.addShip(ShipType.BATTLECRUISER, dir.getDirection(), (int)(Math.random() * 11), (int)(Math.random() * 11));
    sea.addShip(ShipType.BATTLECRUISER, dir.getDirection(), (int)(Math.random() * 11), (int)(Math.random() * 11));
    sea.addShip(ShipType.BATTLECRUISER, dir.getDirection(), (int)(Math.random() * 11), (int)(Math.random() * 11));
    sea.addShip(ShipType.DREADNOUGHT, dir.getDirection(), (int)(Math.random() * 11), (int)(Math.random() * 11));
    sea.addShip(ShipType.DREADNOUGHT, dir.getDirection(), (int)(Math.random() * 11), (int)(Math.random() * 11));
    sea.addShip(ShipType.FLATTOP, dir.getDirection(), (int)(Math.random() * 11), (int)(Math.random() * 11));

    System.out.println(sea.toStringWithShips());

    while (sea.allShipsSunk() != true) {
        int x = (int) (Math.random() * 11);
        int y = (int) (Math.random() * 11);
        int bombCount = 0;
        sea.dropBomb(x, y);
        bombCount++;
        System.out.println("Bomb number: " + bombCount + " on coordinates "
                + x + "," + y + ". Hit Target: " + sea.dropBomb(x,    y));
    }

    System.out.println(sea.toStringWithBombs());
}
}
```

Comment: Why don't you make the enum method static?

Comment: Won't that generate the same direction every time I use it?

Comment: Why would it? `static` means it's a class level method instead of an instance level method, not that the return value of the method never changes.

Comment: Why would it? Did you try it?

Comment: `Direction getDirection` is a factory method. This **must** be either `static` or in its own factory class.

Comment: Of course `Direction.WEST.getDirection()` could be used, but the other options are far better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the method with `Direction.NORTH.getDirection()` (or any other enum value instead of `NORTH`)